# C# WPF slow switch between pages

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-thread

Hello I have issue with switching between pages, if I click very fast between pages it in then end hungs up and then responds back, each page is created as single instance, buttons shares one click event which set frame content, memory usage is stable no increase/decrease in usage, cpu usage while fast clicking on each button is no more than 23%, but UI thread is 100%,

each pages does not have any Loaded/Unloaded events,

each page has KeepAlive="True"

render is using tier 2

Pages are defined like this in Main Window:

```
Opage OPAGE = new Opage();
CPage CPAGE = new CPage();

private void menu_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((Control)sender).Name)
        {
            case "obutton":
            {
                obutton.Background = Brushes.Green;
                cbutton.Background = Brushes.White;
                menu_content_layout.Content = OPAGE;
                break;
            }
            case "cbutton":
            {
                os_button.Background = Brushes.White;
                cpu_button.Background = Brushes.Green;
                menu_content_layout.Content = CPAGE;
                break;
            }
       }
  }
```

If I click on buttons like normal person everything is fine, but while clicking between buttons very fast it hungs up, is there any way to increase app response or should I convert pages to Window, since in one topic it was written that window uses diffrent Thread or should I use something else instead frame?
Also if I seperate button click events would it make any improvement?

EDIT:

```
<Frame x:Name="menu_content_layout" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1007" Margin="0,89,0,0" ClipToBounds="True" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

Comment: what is menu_content_layout?

Comment: Sorry check again I added menu_content_layout